# ReactiveCocoa create a signal producer that can emit manually

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

I want to model the following scenario using ReactiveCocoa in swift.

```
class A{
   let flagSignalProducer = A Signal Producer
   someSignal.takeUntil(a signal that I can trigger manually which is created out of flagSignalProducer).subscribeNext{ (_) in

   }
}
```

How can I create the Signal Producer and use the signal as takeUntil input signal and trigger the signal later manually. Am I doing it right way?

Answer (score 2):

to make a signal that can emit manually you can use `Signal<(), NoError>.pipe()` to get a reference to the signal's "observer", which will allow you to manually send events on the signal.

```
let (flagSignal, flagObserver) = Signal<(), NoError>.pipe()
someSignal.takeUntil(flagSignal).observeNext { _ in

}

//somewhere else, trigger the signal manually with the Observer
flagObserver.sendNext(())
flagObserver.sendCompleted() //complete the signal and free memory
```

and if you need to convert your `flagSignal` to a `SignalProducer` for some reason, there is a `SignalProducer` constructor for that,

```
let flagSignalProducer = SignalProducer(signal: flagSignal)
```